# any idea how to stop HTTP_DOWNLOAD pear package from resuming downloads?

Tags: php, pear

how to force HTTP_DOWNLOAD not to resume downloads ( for free unpaid members for example ,but i'll take care of this ) .. I tried to miss with the range commands , I got it not resuming but in the same time doesn't send the file size and the user will not know how % has completed or how big the file is ....

any help is appreciatd

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be. You could file a feature-request ;-)